# Android MediaStore : Images.Media.insertImage vs ContentResolver.insert

Tags: android, image, android-camera, thumbnails, mediastore

Recently I'm working with a camera app where I need insert all the images I'm doing in the MediaStore. I saw that there is two ways for it, but after read the documentation I don't see any clear difference between both of them.

**Using MediaStore**

```
return Images.Media.insertImage(app.contentResolver, metadata.path, metadata.name, "")
```

**Using ContentResolver**

```
 val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(Images.Media.DATA, metadata.path)
        put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, appImg.mimeType)
        put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, metadata.name)
        put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, currentTime)
        put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, currentTime)
        put(Images.ImageColumns.SIZE, appImg.sizeInBytes)
        put(Images.Media.WIDTH, appImg.width)
        put(Images.Media.HEIGHT, appImg.height)
        appImg[MediaMetadata.Location]?.let {
            put(Images.Media.LATITUDE, it.latitude)
            put(Images.Media.LONGITUDE, it.longitude)
        }
    }

    return app.contentResolver.insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
```

Reading some doc I saw that the second one is also creating a thumbnail, but it doesn't explain if it creates it forever, so this will be store in the MediaStore as well and I will be able to query and retrieve the Thumbnails faster.

Anyone have work with both versions and can explain when to use one or the other?

Answer (score 2):

Although from the [MediaStore](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java) source code it seems that `insertImage()` is equal to using `contentResolver.insert()` with the right values but is also marked as deprecated. So you probably should use the latter.

Also be aware that starting with Android Q (API 29) location data is no longer stored in the MediaStore database (it's stored in Exif meta data). See the media storage [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) for more info on Android Q. Also any `DATA` field will be ignored if you don't have legacy storage enabled or are a system app.

Comment: Hi @CodeRed, I have an issue with a specific case. Would be great if you could find time to check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66148310/storing-images-using-mediastore-crashes-app-on-specific-samsung-devices

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on top of what @CodeRed has reply above, same sample code at https://github.com/android/storage-samples is really helpful. In the sample code, I don't see any MediaStore code and the link above given by @CodeRed is no longer accessible.