# Storing images using MediaStore crashes app on specific Samsung devices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

I have been struggling with this issue for a while and other answers unfortunately didn't give me any clue.

My app allows users to take pictures and store them locally. Everything works fine for most devices, however I experience a crash on **specific Samsung devices running Android 9 (API 28)**.

Example of devices are:
Samsung SM-G955F
Samsung SM-G973F

Here is the method I use to store the images:

```
fun saveMedia(context: Context, uri: Uri) {

    val values = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, IMAGE_PREFIX + Date().toString(DATE_FORMAT) + ".$FILE_EXTENSION")
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, MIME_TYPE)
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis())

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
        } else {
            @Suppress("deprecation")
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, uri.toString())
        }
    }

    val imageCollection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    } else {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    }
    //Crashes here
    val newImageUri = context.contentResolver.insert(imageCollection, values)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

        if (newImageUri == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "unable to insert image: " + values.get(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME))
            throw IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record: "
                    + values.get(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME))
        }

        val bitmapSource = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.applicationContext.contentResolver, uri)
        val bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(bitmapSource)

        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(newImageUri).use { out ->
            bitmap.compress(BITMAP_COMPRESS_FORMAT, 90, out)
        }

        values.clear()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
        context.contentResolver.update(newImageUri, values, null, null)
    }

    load(context)
    cameraFile = null
}
```

On those specific devices the app crashes at `context.contentResolver.insert(imageCollection, values)`
As additional info the saveMedia method receives this as uri: `content://media/external/images/media`

This is the error

```
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):com.myapp.myapp, PID: 3773 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=196677, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.myapp.myapp/com.myapp.ui.MainActivity}: 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4604) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4646) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1947) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7032) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1972) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1594) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at com.myapp.ui.tabs.progress.ProgressViewModel.saveMedia(ProgressViewModel.kt:97) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at com.myapp.ui.tabs.progress.ProgressFragment.onActivityResult(ProgressFragment.kt:185) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:170) 
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7759)
```

I cannot find where it tries to apply `toLowerCase()` nor what object is null.
Am I missing something?

Any hint is highly appreciated
Thank you

Comment: `As additional info the saveMedia method receives this as uri: content://media/external/images/media` You try to put the uri string -that content scheme- in the .DATA column. That will not be accepted as you need a full path there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by changing this line

```
 put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, uri.toString())
```

to this

```
 put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, uri.path)
```

And then load the image with the following differentiating between specific Android versions

```
fun loadPicture(uri: Uri, date: Date) {

  val request = Glide.with(this@ProgressFragment)

  val builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
      request.load(uri)
  } else {
      request.load(File(uri.path!!))
  }

  builder.centerCrop().into(picture)

  pictureDate.text = date.toString(getString(R.string.fragment_progress_date))
}
```